# display Data from URL to html

Tags: javascript, url

This is the URL

https://www.mystore.com/receipt.html?total=100&orderid=ab123

I want to display value of 'total' and 'orderid' in the above url to the below code in a html page.

```
<img src="https://getcurcumin.go2cloud.org/aff_l?order=[orderid]&amount=[total]" width="1" height="1" />
```

so the actual code will read as

```
<img src="https://getcurcumin.go2cloud.org/aff_l?order=ab123&amount=100" width="1" height="1" />
```

after taking values from the URL

What javascript code can I use? Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: See `window.location`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var total = getQueryVariable("total");
var orderid = getQueryVariable("orderid");
alert(total);
alert(orderid);
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: if I use the above code, will it automatically send the values?

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = window.location.search.split('&'),
    total = query[0].split('=')[1],    // "100"
    orderid = query[1].split('=')[1];  // "ab123"
```

Comment: will this insert a code automatically in the code? after taking values from the url?